# How to add Mobile number with only integer in CRM module in OpenERP

Tags: postgresql, odoo, openerp-7

In the CRM module there is a mobile number field. But it is a `char` field I can add alphabetic characters also. I'd prefer it to work with numerals only. So I replaced `mobile:fields.char('Mobile',size=20)` with `mobile:field.integer('Mobile')`, but I can add up-to 9 digits. Is there any other way to add mobile number with integers only?
We use PostgreSQL,so there is numeric as one datatype, so I also tried `mobile:fields.numeric('Mobile',size=10)` it is throwing me an error as:

```
"datatype not used in module".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use regular expression to validate**

```
import re
from osv import osv,fields
class crm_lead_inherit(osv.osv):
    _name = _inherit = 'crm.lead'
    def create(self,cr,uid,vals,context=None):   
       if 'mobile' in vals and vals['mobile']:
            if re.match("^[0-9]*$", vals['mobile']) != None:
               pass
            else:
               raise osv.except_osv(_('Invalid Mobile No'),_('Please enter a valid Phone Number'))   
       return super(crm_lead_inherit, self).create(cr, uid,vals, context=context)
   def write(self,cr,uid,ids,vals,context=None):   
       if 'mobile' in vals and vals['mobile']:
            if re.match("^[0-9]*$", vals['mobile']) != None:
               pass
            else:
               raise osv.except_osv(_('Invalid Mobile No'),_('Please enter a valid Phone Number'))   
       return super(crm_lead_inherit, self).write(cr, uid,ids,vals, context=context)
crm_lead_inherit()
```

Comment: @Senthilnathang : I'm new to Openerp Can you please tell me where should i paste this code

Comment: @Senthilnathang i'm getting this error "   if re.match("^[0-9]*$", vals['mobile']) != None:
NameError: global name 're' is not defined"

Comment: @nitesh check answer again

Comment: you need to override write function also

Comment: yes whenever you change value u and update u need to use this code in write function also coz create first time when u create record

Answer (score 1):

senthilnathang solution is partially correct. Also it is not good to modify the create, write, search functionalities. So my opinion is to use the on_change functionality for the field mobile.
In the xml view add the onchange

```
<field name="mobile" on_change="onchange_mobile(mobile)"/>
```

Then in the python file for the crm lead, inside the crmlead class,

```
def onchange_mobile(self, cr, uid, ids, mobile, context=None):
    if not mobile:
        return {}
    mobile = mobile.replace('.','') #removes any '.' from the string
    mobile = mobile.replace(' ','') #removes space from the string
    if not mobile.isdigit():
        raise osv.except_osv(_('Invalid Mobile No'),_('Please enter a valid Phone Number'))   
    return {}
```

You can remove the replace part if you want.

Comment: yes you can check and raise exception using  on_change also